# Selected device could not run on Xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios

My Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127) and my Mac OS is 10.7.5. I installed valid provisioned profile and certificates also. When I deploy Xcode through device it shows error `No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination`. If anyone know can you solve my problem?

Comment: What version of iOS is your device running?

Answer (score 2):

10.7.5 is your Mac OS X version number, not your iOS device version.

The problem is you do not have valid Provisioning Profile. Go to Apple Developer Center > Provisioning Portal to create necessary App ID and Provisioning Profile.

Alternatively, right click on your device in Xcode > Organizer to "Add to Provisioning Portal"

Comment: Provisioning pofiles are already installed.There is something other issue

Comment: installed, but is it valid and containing your device's UDID ? Did you create an App ID for your App?

Answer (score 2):

How about selecting "Use this phone for development" in the Devices pane of the Organizer?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode now creates applications for ARM7 by default.

To support the iPhone 3G and other arm6 devices, you need to specify arm6 and arm7 in in the Architectures list, and set the device requirements to only arm6 in the plist.

It depends that what device you are using. If its iOS6 device then its ok with default else use above setting.

Answer (score 0):

Check your selected deployment target , select this according to your device iOS version.

[image]

Comment: and which version of os in your device

Comment: Ipod 6.1.2(10B146) and its ipod genereation is 4g

Comment: hey download latest xcode which have 6.1 in there deployment targer

Comment: but on app store latest Xcode is 4.6 while i am already using Xcode 4.6

Comment: so what is the highest deployment target ?

Answer (score 0):

Shivan's answer (Alternatively, right click on your device in Xcode > Organizer to "Add to Provisioning Portal") helped me with the same problem with the additional step of then disconnecting the device (USB) and reconnecting.